# How can I build an event recording

Tags: excel, recording

In my organization (Baggage handling system), we need to record every error occur in the system, it is a new system so we are using paper to record the errors. 
what I need is to build a program that makes things easier. 
An error recorder program, which store the value in an excel sheets (backup) and can also export a daily report that contain all the errors that occur in one day in excel sheet. 
in general specking : how to make a program interact (input, output) with excel sheets? and which is better to me Java or VB .net? 
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: So, several questions need to be considered such as how many errors per day? What information needs to be stored - just one number, or date, time, location, size, weight, value, national or international? You need to think about your question and the parameters and then make an attempt But if the numbers are low then excel may be suitable but if they are high a programmed approach or a bespoke database application could be better.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, actually I need to store a date, time of start and end (I need it to calculate the duration in minute), Conveyor number (for example: 0012.44.01), type of error (drop-down list), remarks (take input from user in text) and area (drop-down list). and some more comments and drop-down lists. This all type of inputs in each error need to be stored in excel is it possible ? if not what can solve my problem ? and thanks again.